# For comprehension with Future[Option[T]] and executing subsequent futures based on conditions

Tags: scala, playframework

How would you do, using **for comprehensions**, with futures returning an option, that is Future[Option[T]], and executing subsequent futures if and only if a condition is met, like for example, the second future should be executed only if the first future has a non empty value on a given field?

Not sure if I'm explaining myself well enough what i'm trying to achieve but here is some code that isn't working for me:

```
def show(id: Int, slug: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  for {
    aWithbTuple <- someDAO.findByIDJoined(id)
    cID = aWithbTuple.map(_._1.cID).get if aWithbTuple.isDefined
    c <- cDAO.findByID(cID) //Load the c table record only if the cID field is present in the first member of the tuple of aWithbTuple
  } yield {
    aWithbTuple.fold(NotFound) { case (a, b) =>
      Ok(views.html.show(a, b, c))
    }
  }
}
```

It compiles well but I get an exception if the first future's result is **None**, what i'd like to get is a **None** as result if the first future returns **None**, but it seems that even if the first future returns **None**, the second future still gets executed and I get an exception as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that the `if` in the *for-comprehension* isn't a *postfix conditional* as you might find in some other languages. It is instead, a *filter* operation.

The difference is that as a postfix conditional, it would prevent the action preceeding it from being executed if the conditional fails. As a filter, however, the action is executed and then then filter is used to determine whether to proceed. Because of this you are failing on `aWithbTuple.map(_._1.cID).get` since the `get` throws when the option is a `None`.

If you used the `if` as a filter on the future `someDAO.findByIDJoined(id)` instead, it will short-circuit the *for-comprehension* with a failed future when `aWithbTuple` is `None`, thus allowing you to safely call `get`:

```
def show(id: Int, slug: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
  for {
    aWithbTuple <- someDAO.findByIDJoined(id) if aWithbTuple.isDefined
    cID = aWithbTuple.map(_._1.cID).get
    c <- cDAO.findByID(cID) //Load the c table record only if the cID field is present in the first member of the tuple of aWithbTuple
  } yield {
    aWithbTuple.fold(NotFound) { case (a, b) =>
      Ok(views.html.show(a, b, c))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Arne, was totally thinking that if condition in a for-comprehension should work as in the traditional languages. Seems like someone needs to go back and open that Odersky book again :\